# What are the points in a SVG relative to?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following simple SVG:

```
<div class="svg-wrapper">


            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 194 186" class="circliful">
                <g stroke="#ccc">
                    <line x1="133" y1="50" x2="140" y2="40" stroke-width="2" />
                </g>
                <g stroke="#ccc">
                    <line x1="140" y1="40" x2="200" y2="40" stroke-width="2" />
                </g>
                <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="57" class="border" fill="#eee" stroke="none" stroke-width="15" stroke-dasharray="360" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
                <circle class="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="57" class="border" fill="none" stroke="#3498DB" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0,20000" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
                <text text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="110" class="icon" style="font-size: 40px" fill="#3498DB">&#xf206</text>
                <text class="timer" text-anchor="middle" x="175" y="35" style="font-size: 22px; undefined;" fill="#aaa">0%</text>


        </div>
```

Now if you notice the SVG carefully, you will see that there are attibutes like the following:

```
x1="133" y1="50" x2="140" y2="40"
```

And the following for the circle:

```
 cx="100" cy="100" r="57" ,
```

I just have one question about this, are these points relative to the document? Now I tried the following:

```
.svg-wrapper  {
            position: relative;
            top: 200px;
            left: 200px;
            max-width: 200px;
        }
```

I.E. Moved the container a bit by using `position:relative`, and the circle moved too, now I beleive if those points where relative to the document the circle should't have moved, but it clearly did and so it means that the following points are not relative to the document:

```
cx="100" cy="100" r="57"
```

And

```
x1="133" y1="50" x2="140" y2="40"
```

If not the document, then what are these points relative to? Can anybody explain?

Comment: SVG creates its own context. The numbers are relative to the context or previous point along the path, based on lower or upper case of the syntax.

Comment: @Leo can you be a bit more elaborate or post an answer . thank you.

Comment: This is too broad, I'm afraid I can't explain all in a single post. I suggest you learn some SVG fundamentals from [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate values are relative to the origin of the SVG, which is the top left of the SVG viewport.

The viewPort is defined by the `<svg>` element's width and height attributes.  If you move the SVG by moving the container it is in, you move the SVG.  Just the same as if it was an `<img>`, `<canvas>` etc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the points are relative to the container, which would be in line with normal HTML in the sense that if you place an element within a container it's position then becomes relative to the container rather than the entire document.

Comment: @Brain Thanks thats exactly what i taught .. can you validate this with any HTML documentation ? Thanks